# Selecting checkbox from the line that contains word Capybara

Tags: ruby, checkbox, html-table, capybara

I have been searching answer for week.
I need to create automatic tests and one of them has to delete a line from table. This line looks like this:

#### Html looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" class="name" rowspan="1">
      <a href="/mpromoter/whitelist/edit/3">Capybara852</a>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" class="description" rowspan="1">This whitelist is added by Capybara automated test</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="whitelistType" rowspan="1">Internal</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="status" rowspan="1">None</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="active" rowspan="1">false</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="msCount" rowspan="1">40</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="modifiedBy" rowspan="1">admin</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="modifiedOn" rowspan="1">26.06.2014 11:08</td>
    <td colspan="1" class="selected" rowspan="1">
      <input class="check" onclick="disableButton('delete', false);" id="check_0" name="check_0" type="checkbox">
      <img id="check_0_icon" class="t-error-icon" alt="" src="/mpromoter/assets/4716a6a0a357181/core/spacer.gif" style="display: none;">
   </td>
</tr>
```

I need to check this checkbox that stands in the same line where is written Capybara. I can't select this checkbox because its id may be different every time I run these automatic tests.

#### I am asking, how can I select checkbox without its own id or name or class, I need to select checkbox that stands in the same line that contains Capybara

It is a href part there.

I can select checkbox with its id. But I want to select the checkbox with unknown id from the line that contains the word capybara :)

I have tried many different things but nothing works...

So I am asking for some help. What I have to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand what are you asking but...
So you can take each row from your table and then check if the row has the value 'Capybara'

```
$('#stack tbody tr').find('td a').text().match(new RegExp('Capybara'))
```

If that is true, from the same row do what you want with the checkbox.
I need to do to many things to give you a capybara version, but you just need to translate that to capybara.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the approach you use be:

1. Determine how you can `find` the row you want (ie contains "Capybara")
2. Use the `within` method to find the checkbox within that row

For example, you can find any row that contains the word "Capybara" anywhere using:

```
find('tr', :text => 'Capybara')
```

You can use these same `find` options in `within`. When finding the checkbox within the `within` block, Capybara will only search in that row. So if you do not care where the word "Capybara" shows up in the row, you can do:

```
within('tr', :text => 'Capybara') do
  find('input.check').set(true)
end
```

If needed, you can change the `within` options to be more specific. For example, you might only want rows where the first column, which has class "name", has the word "Capybara" (rather than "Capybara" just being in the description column). This could be done with:

```
within(:xpath, '//tr[td[@class="name" and contains(., "Capybara")]]') do
  find('input.check').set(true)
end
```